# Почему иногда невозможно обойтись без таких слов как «некоторый» или «определённый»? Какое правило нарушается?

Tags: синтаксис, значение-слов

Рассмотрим примеры из [Большого толкового словаря](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9):

> **НЕКОТОРЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; ***местоим. прил.*** 1. Какой-то, точно не определённый. *Н-ое время все молчали. В некоторых местах ткань проела
> моль. Н-ое количество зерна оставили на сев.*

*«Некоторое количество зерна оставили на сев»* — нельзя убрать «некоторое»: *«Количество зерна оставили на сев»*.

*«Некоторое время все молчали»* — нельзя сказать просто: *«Время все молчали»*.

Можно сказать: *«День все молчали»*, но просто: *«Время все молчали»* — сказать нельзя. Надо сказать: *«Некоторое или определённое время все молчали»*.

Возможно, эти слова требуются перед неисчисляемыми существительными:
«день» — исчисляемое существительное, значит ненужны или необязательны слова «некоторый» или «определённый», а «время» — неисчисляемое существительное и поэтому требуется сказать: «некоторое или определённое время».

Однако предложение *«В некоторых местах ткань проела моль»* — тоже не особо звучит без «некоторых» или «определённых»: *«В местах ткань проела моль»*. Хочется добавить: *«В **некоторых** или **определённых** местах…»*

Эти слова являются определениями. Толкование «определения» следующее:

> **ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ**, -я; ср. ... 4. *Лингв.* Второстепенный член предложения, обозначающий качество, свойство или другой признак
> предмета.
>
> [[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)]

Но если задуматься над значением этих слов, например, слова «некоторый»:

> **НЕКОТОРЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; ***местоим. прил.*** 1. Какой-то, точно не определённый.
>
> [[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9)]

То складывается впечатление, что они не обозначают ни признак, ни свойство — они вообще не дают никакой новой информации: *«некоторый — какой-то, точно не определённый»*.

Тем не менее есть случаи в которых без этих слов обойтись нельзя. **Для чего же они используются и какое правило нарушается при их отсутствии?**

Comment: Некоторое -- это в данных вами случаях обозначает "не всё". То есть не всё время, а часть его -- некоторое время. Получается, что обозначаемое свойство -- это ограниченность (пусть и не точная).

Comment: @Nektoid Спасибо, за ваш комментарий. Я тоже думал над таким вариантом, однако это другое значение слова. В той же [словарной статье из Большого толкового словаря](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9) есть толкование под номером 3: «Не все, отдельные. _Н-ые мои друзья ушли на пенсию. Н-ые платья вышли из моды. Н-ые сотрудники опоздали, а н-ые совсем не пришли на собрание_». Я же говорю о толковании под номером 1: «Какой-то, точно не определённый».

Comment: По-видимому, в ваших случаях слово "некоторые" используется именно в третьем значении, а не в первом. Что же касается определения, то "некоторое", как видно, не определение, а часть подлежащего ("некоторое количество зерна оставили": основа предложения). Подлежащее может выражаться словосочетанием (см. здесь: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/vyrazhenie-podlezhaschego.html#i-3). То же и в случае с 'некоторое время все молчали': "некоторое время" — это обстоятельство из двух слов. Такое тоже бывает.

Comment: @Nektoid В тексте моего вопроса сказано, что примеры взяты из словаря, а именно из примеров к первому определению. Все три предложения взяты из примеров Большого толкового словаря к первому определению.

Comment: @Nektoid Насчёт того, что это не определение, то хотелось бы услышать больше аргументов на этот счёт. По вашей ссылке нет примеров именно со словами «некоторый» и «определённый». «В некоторых местах…» — в местах _каких?_ некоторых — чем не определение? «Некоторое количество зерна...» — количество _какое?_ некоторое.

Comment: @Nektoid Мой вопрос заключается больше в том, почему эти слова требуются. Можно сказать: _«У них было время молчать»_, но нельзя сказать: _«Время они молчали»_ — нужно только добавить _«**Некоторое** время…»_

Comment: Не определение именно потому, что теряется смысл при изъятии из основы. Что касается вопроса, то по моей ссылке имеются примеры составных подлежащих: *около десяти человек*; *больше слов*. Они, по вашей логике, тоже должны разбиваться: *около десяти (кого?) человек*, *больше (кого?) слов*. Но не всякое слово, к которому можно задать вопрос, автоматически является другим членом предложения.

Comment: @Nektoid При изъятии основы предложения потеряется смысл любого предположения, потому что подлежащее и сказуемое как раз и несут не себе основе содержание, а второстепенные члены предложения его дополняют. Я не понимаю Вашего аргумента про изъятие основы.

Comment: @Nektoid По поводу ваших примеров. Тут имеет место случай, когда подлежащее выражено _«именем существительным, выражающим количество, + существительным в родительном падеже: множество народа, ряд лиц, часть приезжих»_ [Википедия]. Около десяти человек: «около десяти» — количество, «человек» — в родильном падеже. Больше слов: «больше» — большее количество, «слов» — в родильном падеже.

Comment: @Nektoid В примерах из словаря: «время» и «количество» — именинный падеж, «местах» — предложный падеж. Под приведенное выше правило эти примеры не подпадают.

Comment: Я написал: "При изъятии *из* основы".

Comment: @Nektoid Вы могли привести пример «изъятия из основы». Я не понимаю, о чём вы говорите.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ исправлен (доработка текста)

1. ***"Время все молчали"?***

Странное какое-то предложение, так не говорят. Существительному "время" требуется определение: ***Некоторое время все молчали.*** Но что же это за слово, которое без определения не используется?

**ВРЕМЯ**, ср. 1. **Филос**. Основная (наряду с пространством) форма существования бесконечно развивающейся материи. 2. **Отрезок**, промежуток в последовательной смене минут, часов, дней, лет и т.п. На короткое в. Уделять много времени учёбе.

2. Итак,  это **отрезок времени,** а величину отрезка нужно указывать. Измерить или определить примерно. Вот и получается некоторое (= неопределенное или незначительное) время. То есть речь идет не о времени в философском его понимании, а именно об отрезке времени.
3. Так что **не лишнее** это слово, а совершенно необходимое. Но не с ним здесь надо разбираться, а **с существительными**, которым обязательно требуется определение по семантическим показателям.

Другими словами, **это параметры,** которым нужно числовое значение их величины, и в этой функции часто используются местоименные прилагательные с неопределенным значением.

4. **О нечленимых словосочетаниях**

[Синтаксис современного русского языка](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)  стр. 7 – 9

К нечленимым относятся словосочетания с параметрами, которые сами по себе **не несут достаточной информации,** в том числе температура, вес и др. Нельзя сказать: хранить при температуре. Поэтому эти существительные требуют распространения определениями.

Очевидно, к этим параметрам можно отнести такие слова, как ***место, время***.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А почему же тогда можно сказать: «У них было время молчать», но нельзя сказать: «Время они молчали». Что в перовом случае философское определение, а во втором «отрезок времени»? Но похоже, что в первом случае тоже речь идёт об отрезке: был какой-то отрезок времени, в течение которого можно было молчать.

Comment: Про нечленимые словосочетания — это может иметь место. Однако в приведённой Вами ссылке, подходят, как я понял, «количественно-именные словосочетания». Но тут, что получается: если существительное в именительном падеже, что количество можно убрать. Например, из пункта 1: три тетради — «Семён купил три тетради» или просто «Семён купил тетради». Смысл менее точный, но предложение звучит. 1/2

Comment: А вот если падеж родительный то, количество убрать нельзя: несколько человек — «Пришло несколько человек» или «Пришло человек». Уже не звучит. Из этого следует, что причина не в неделимости словосочетания, а в родительном падеже. Если убрать количество, то предложение оказывается несогласованным. «Три тетради» же, хотя и являются в конкретном предложении синтаксически неделимыми, в целом «тетради» могут использоваться без количества, потому что имеют падеж именительный. 2/2

Comment: Про температуру хороший пример. Но я не вижу в приведённой Вами ссылке информацию об этом. Может, я просто не нашёл. Вы могли бы написать, где можно почитать об этом. «Места» немного не подходят, на мой взгляд, под количество. Тут скорее речь идёт о расположении в пространстве. Может быть, необходимость наличия определения касается слов связных с пространственно-временными измерениями или измерениями каких-то величин? Надо подумать над этим.

Comment: Поскольку ответ был полезен, я поставил отметку. Но ясности до конца всё равно нет, по этому на данный момент как принятый не отмечаю.

Comment: Ничего, ничего, я не в претензии, если пока нельзя принять, и спасибо за голос. А вы, конечно, подумайте.  Вот вам еще тема для размышления. Язык людей – это не механический язык роботов: разные ситуации – разное применение слов. В одном случае –  обычное словосочетание, а в другом – неделимое, если требуется количественное определение. "У них было время молчать". Это И.п. "Время они молчали." А здесь какой падеж? Тоже подумайте.

Comment: С падежом интересный вопрос. Слово «время» в таком виде может быть в двух падежах: в именительном и винительном. И да, действительно, в этом случае винительный падеж. Однако возьмём слово, которое меняется: «Одну минуту они молчали» или «Минуту они молчали». «Одну» использовать необязательно. Складывается впечатление, что разница в исчисляемости. Потому что минуты посчитать можно, а вот время напрямую посчитать нельзя, нужно использовать какие-то единицы измерения. Нельзя сказать «одно время», «два времени», «три времени», а «одна минута», «две минуты», «три минуты» — может быть.

Comment: Так же и температура. Мы можем говорить о количестве градусов, а о количестве температур нет. И то же самое с массой, скоростью, мощность и т. п. Нельзя сказать: «Он ехал со скоростью» или «Предмет массы», нужно добавить определения: «большой скоростью» или «большой массы».

Comment: Вы меня с примером про температуру навели на мысль, что в данном случае нельзя употреблять названия физических величин (измеряемых количеств) без определений. Скорей всего, потому, что само название физической величины не даёт информации, только в сочетании с определением можно понять о каком количестве и чего идёт речь. И когда количество точно назвать нельзя, используют слова «некоторый» или «определённый», чтоб мысль звучала законченной.